# How to get a XML with very large data into a varchar(MAX) variable in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, varchar

In MS SQL, I have large XML data which i want to cast and store it in a varchar(MAX) variable but its not working. when i try to capture the data in varchar variable it is missing some part of the data.I want to cast the data because want to do some string manipulations which i cant do it if the data is in XML format.Please suggest some alternative solutions.

Comment: Specify *but its not working*.

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: It's probably not missing any part of the data, but there are plenty of ways to get a value truncated: by incorrectly mixing in non-`MAX` types and getting implicit conversions, calling functions that only accept non-`MAX` types (up to 4000/8000 characters), using `PRINT`, or using Management Studio to inspect the result. All of these have their own problems, but internally a flat conversion from `XML` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` (or better `NVARCHAR(MAX)`) will work.

Comment: What does *In MS SQ, I have...* mean (XML typed column?)? What does *large* mean? What does *store* mean (in another column, to the file system...)? Where do you examine, if the result is complete?

Comment: Reading this again, the most important question might be, what this means: *"because want to do some string manipulations which i cant do it if the data is in XML format"*?

Comment: In relation to your "it is missing some part of the data" statement, is the XML only US-ASCII character data? If the XML contains UTF-8 or international characters you might be better off casting it to `nvarchar(max)` instead of `varchar(max)`.

Comment: You should be able to the manipulation using xml directly. CAST xml to string will get the escaped value